# Problems Upgrading Scala, Play and SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Play application using Scala. The current working version uses:

Playframework: 2.5.18
Scala: 2.11.7
Sbt: 0.13.11

But everything breaks when I upgrade the above to the following versions below:

Playframework: 2.6.17
Scala: 2.12.6
Sbt: 1.1.6

And by everything breaks, I mean when I sbt reloads in my IDE (Intellij) it fails with the following error:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/me/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /project/project
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /project
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.33 is selected over 0.32
[warn]      +- com.typesafe:npm_2.12:1.2.1                        (depends on 0.32)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web:1.4.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 0.32)
[warn]  * org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:3.0.17 is selected over {2.1, 1.5.5}
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.2.2              (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.2.2   (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:3.2.2       (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.2.2                 (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.2.2                  (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.2.2              (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.2.2      (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.2.2         (depends on 3.0.17)
[warn]      +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:1.3      (depends on 1.5.5)
[warn]      +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.0.0.M5  (depends on 2.1)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:23.0 is selected over {10.0.1, 16.0, 20.0}
[warn]      +- io.methvin:directory-watcher:0.3.2                 (depends on 23.0)
[warn]      +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.8.8 (depends on 10.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.0.0.M5  (depends on 10.0.1)
[warn]      +- com.spotify:docker-client:8.9.0                    (depends on 10.0.1)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[error] /project/Grunt.scala:14:9: Java class java.lang.Process is not a value
[error]         Process("grunt build", base).run
[error]         ^
[error] /project/Grunt.scala:18:29: Java class java.lang.Process is not a value
[error]         watchProcess = Some(Process("grunt watch", base).run)
[error]                             ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
Invalid response.
```

If I run just `sbt compile` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /project
[error] /project/Grunt.scala:14:9: Java class java.lang.Process is not a value
[error]         Process("grunt build", base).run
[error]         ^
[error] project/Grunt.scala:18:29: Java class java.lang.Process is not a value
[error]         watchProcess = Some(Process("grunt watch", base).run)
[error]                             ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I am really at a total loss with regards to what could be going wrong and how to fix it. Is it imcompatibility issue between the versions? Is it due to some things being deprecated? I cant really tell...Googling around has also not helped.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, or what could be going wrong would be really appreciated!

*Update*
Looking at the compile error, I initially thought that I have Java Process imported, but here is the import section in the file giving the compilation error:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

import play.sbt.PlayRunHook
import sbt._
```

It should be noted that all these was working perfectly before. The only changes made was to upgrade Scala/Play/SBT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `Process`.

You have imported `java.lang.Process`, while you need `scala.sys.process.Process`

As stated in [sbt 1.0.0 release notes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html#sbt+1.0.0)

> sbt.Process and sbt.ProcessExtra are dropped. Use scala.sys.process instead

Comment: I do not think that is the case. I updated the question with the import statments

Comment: I've update the response with a reference from sbt release notes. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the problem. Another reason I should consider not using wildcard imports like 'sbt._'